# sqlite WHERE query

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

I am trying to query SQLite in flask using the following

```
cur = g.db.execute('select * from movies where category = action')
```

but I receive the following error

```
OperationalError: no such column: action
```

How can I execute the query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should quote action to make it a string and not a column.

```
 cur = g.db.execute('select * from movies where category = "action"')
```